# DataSpell error: I cannot run Python 3.6.13 with dataspell

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, runtime-error, dataspell

I'm trying to use my Anaconda Environment where I have installed Python 3.6.13 within `DataSpell 2023.1.3`, but I'm
getting an error which I cannot fix. Also, I do not see the top menu `file`,`view`,etc. Any help ? Thank you in advance.

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try set encoding default in Pycharm, maybe is not configured
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sGsZ.png)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I do not know what you mean.See **EDIT** on what I have found by your hint.

Comment: Click on "enter image description here" to see the image example, sorry

Comment: Yes, I have clicked on it, but your hint doesn't work, I can still see the `Run Error` :-(

Comment: Try run jupyter outside the Pycharm, try run in terminal only, I think that problem is on Pycharm. Remove the environment before, and create a new one.